# Edit core data entry

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I have an application which is currently using and storing data in Core Data. My data moel looks like this:[image]

My client has requested the ability to amend the Number (in Customer entity), or any of the attributes in 'Rooms' (except CustomerName).

I not sure where to start with this. I have done some googling and searching of questions, but cant seem to find a solution that fits my need.

Any help or sample code would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Sam

Comment: [https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdRelationships.html](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdRelationships.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the number using the key value coding or by accessing its method directly

```
Customer* customer=[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Customer" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
customer.Number=[NSNumber numberWithInt:10];
if(![managedObjectContext save:&err])
    NSLog(@"data cannot be saved");
```

You can access the Rooms entity in a similar way,which will be returned as NSSet* object.
Get the required object  in that and modify the value in a similar fashion.